# Issue using Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm new using Google Calendar API and I have some questions. First of all, I need to know if there is some way to grant access all the time to anyone in order to make entries in my calendar.

For example, I'm developing a web application using javascript and php. The scope of the application is make reservations. The user fills a form and then send the information. What I want to do is, at the same time the user is sending the form, send an entry to my google calendar.

I have been reading about that but I only find that is necessary to have a token access all the time for anyone.

Can you give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should only allow one user to your Calendar, that one user is your website's back end.

Comment: yeah. i'm going to try something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your application being a reservations app, I'd suggest you use [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) so the users don't need to "login". This is because the Service Account belongs to the application instead of the user. This can also solve your inquiry regarding access grant all the time when making entries in the calendar.

@daimto has an article in [his website](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/) about using PHP along with Calendars and Service Accounts. Check it out as it seems to be informative.